# I cant run the email intent code on my phone

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roqTP.png)

the email intent code is completely run in the android mobile model provided by android studio but when I run the code in my personal phone its not work…
please answer ??

Comment: I there any error in you log

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to set the type of intent so it will trigger email clients

```
   Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to});  
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);  
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);  
           
    //need this to prompts email client only  
    email.setType("message/rfc822");  
      
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin code,

```
val selectorIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
selectorIntent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:")
val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf<String>("mail id"))
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject")
emailIntent.selector = selectorIntent
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."))
```

Java code,

```
Intent selectorIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
selectorIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"mail id"});
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
emailIntent.setSelector(selectorIntent);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
intEmail.setType("plain/text");
intEmail.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
intEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"receiver_email_address"});
            
 if (intEmail.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
    startActivity(intEmail);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code of mayar hassan, it worked fine on my side. [on Samsung Android 8.1]

The code:

```
public class TestSentMail extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_sent_mail);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            submitOrder();
        });
    }

    private void submitOrder() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "coffe order for tancolo");
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

The screenshot:

[image: sent email screenshot]

**How to fix your problem**

In general, I think we should do these as below.

1. Check the log in the Logcat panel in Android Studio, maybe there are exceptions.
2. Added your debug code where you want to add.

Answer (score 0):

```
val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    i.type = "message/rfc822"
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf<String>("sumsolutions.net@gmail.com"))
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback")
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text here...")
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."))
    } catch (ex: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
    }
```